# "Invalid username or password" when registering and logging in a user

Tags: users

I'm having a really weird issue with user registration. I've got verification turned off, and logging in after activation turned on, so that when a user registers then checks out, it's a seamless flow. And this works. But the login form at `/login` does not. Whenever I try to create an account I get this in the logs:

```
$_POST=array (
  'action' => 'users/saveUser',
  'redirect' => '/confirm-account',
  'firstName' => 'Test',
  'lastName' => 'User',
  'email' => 'testuser9181@gmail.com',
  'password' => REDACTED,
)

$_SESSION=array (
  '8dfc5494412903b44af114111435fc5cYii.CWebUser.flash.error' => 'Invalid username or password.',
  '8dfc5494412903b44af114111435fc5cYii.CWebUser.flashcounters' => 
  array (
    'error' => 0,
  ),
)
```

Any idea what might be going on here? I have no idea what's causing this, and why it's working on one page and not the other. I can copy/paste the registration code from the checkout page and it will not work at `/login`. The same template is being extended.

Comment: Fixed by updating to 2.6.2997

Comment: It might be a good idea to accept your own answer so the question is marked as "solved"

Comment: I tried, I can't accept my own answer for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by upgrading to 2.6.2997.